# Math.floor() returning undefined value

Tags: javascript

I just create a random number generator range between 0 to p. but, I am often getting an undefined return value? I have to use an if condition to avoid that. I want to know Why I need to do so?

```js
function rangen(p){
var ran = Math.floor((Math.random() * p))*100;
if (ran == undefined){
    console.log(ran);
    rangen(p);            
}
return(ran); 
}    

var fw = rangen(5);
var fh = rangen(7);
console.log("fh: " + fh + "fw: " + fw);
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce.  `ran` should never be undefined unless `p` is undefined.

Comment: Can't reproduce either: https://jsfiddle.net/yt6nLq33/

Comment: ok, why p should be undefined, I am giving a valid input!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error either https://jsfiddle.net/xedret/hks4dm4r/

Comment: `Math.floor` *never* returns `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: I don't know, you tell us.  *How* are you getting `ran` as undefined?

Comment: `p` is definitely not `undefined` in the demo, and that wouldn't matter anyway. Like @Bergi stated, `Math.floor` will never return `undefined`. If you're running this in the console, it'll show `undefined` becuase of the return value of `console.log()`.

Comment: The question needs code that reproduces the problem *as is*.  This can't be answered.

Comment: I cannot reproduce either

Comment: https://github.com/grnbird/Monkeyboo
here is the full code!

Comment: It cannot be reproduced, no matter how you try. I second to @Bergi 's statement.
OP, please make sure the code you have in the question reproduces the problem without any specific conditions (though if there are any, please explicitly mention it).

Answer (score -2):

Try to use:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 % p);
```

Comment: Hi Newbie, Please try to add supporting information instead direct or nearby solution. It helps to understand the solution and concepts